# How to set a new home directory at every login?

Tags: bash, login

I'm in the process of building a kiosk system and need to give the guest user a new temporary home directory at every login. 
I wrote a little bash script that takes care of that but when it tries to change the home directory of the user it throws the error 'usermod: user guest is currently used by process 20465'

The script itself look as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
NEW_RAND =$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)

mkdir /tmp/guest-$NEW_RAND
chown guest:guest /tmp/guest-$NEW_RAND
ln -s /etc/guest /tmp/guest-$NEW_RAND
usermod -d /tmp/guest-$NEW_RAND guest
```

How would I force the user into that new home directory?

Best regards

Edit: Just to clarify I run the script on login via .bashrc.

Comment: `.bashrc` is a bit too late. This should be done as early in the process as possible, possibly via PAM.

Comment: why so difficult? deleting and restoring the content of the home from a backup is not enough? and what muru said :+)

Comment: If you use the standard guest account of Ubuntu, that automatically creates a new temporary home directory on every log-in. Why are you not simply using that one?

Comment: I thought about it but it seemed too easy, and I wanted full control over the process of creating the system. But I think I'm going to think about sticking with the guest user. 

Regarding PAM as far as I can see the scripts that pam_scripts for example would execute would be executed regardless of the user that logs in. That wouldn't do in a multi-user setup.

Comment: @expired sure it would, you just want the ones executed right after login, when the username has been set (not 100% sure, but such should exist). By the way, that's a very convoluted way of getting a random string, you could simplify it to: `tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c8`.

Comment: @terdon `pam_exec` is provided with username via the env var `PAM_USER`, so that should work http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pam_exec.8.html (also `mktemp` with suitable options might be best of all)

Comment: I can write up an answer for this tomorrow. Basic, you have a compressed file-system ready to go, with user account programs, whatever else. On boot, you create some virtual disk space, decompress your image, and run the applications of your kiosk in memory. when the system reboots, your file-system isn't changed, but all the user data is gone (from memory). Thats a pretty old school way to do it, but it will work, every time.  to build the image user directory the first time, you could use usermod -d user.    if you try to build your file-system each time you boot, it will be slower.

Comment: muru is right, this will be late, i would suggest to have a diff logic. Like a daily cron to change the userdir. Do check if the user is logged before executing the cron.

Comment: @expired as suggested by  Byte Commander you may use the build in guest account and **you do have**  control of the process....

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the building guest account as suggested by [Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander) ?
You can have a full control of the process by modifying the needed files. There is a good overview at [help.unbuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) .

So skeleton files go in `/etc/guest-session/skel` and custom commands go in `/etc/guest-session/prefs.sh` .